# execute function of command handler is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm learning node through making a discord bot, my goal is to learn how databases interact with clients through making a discord bot. And I have run into an error in my bot in the command handler.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
> client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);**

Index File Part that the error occurs at.

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLocaleLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
});
```

This next part is the actual command

```
    name: 'ping',
    description: "Simple Ping Command",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send(`Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms. Bot Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`);
    }
}
```

Comment: It means `client.commands.get('ping')` is undefined. Is your ping file in the `commands` folder?

Comment: Yes it is
https://gyazo.com/a33b1e9b62e7db9bca85944bd37885e1

Comment: Have you initialized a new collection using `client.commands = new Discord.Collection()` before you require and load your commands?

Comment: Yes I have fixed the issue by using 'use' instead of execute,

Answer (score 0):

ISSUE FIXED: Used 'use' function instead of 'execute' Function.